# Django open pdf on certain page number

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, python-pdfreader

I am trying to create a PDF analysis web app and I am stuck. I want to allow the user to open a certain page of the pdf that have over 300 pages in it.
So, can anyone tell me how to use Django to open the pdf in a new tab on a specific page?

---

**EDIT --**  Actually the Django code is running on AWS server and I want the user to see and open a PDF on a specific page that is stored into my media folder after analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this really isn't Django-specific and is going to depend on what viewer you are using to display the PDF. If you're relying on the browser to display it, according to [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html), you can use an anchor link (#page=) in the url (e.g. **http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=XX**) though I think support for this varies outside Firefox and Chrome.

If you're using [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js), on the other hand, you'll be able to programatically select a page to render. You can see how to do that on the viewer's examples page, [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/).

Comment: Actually the Django code is running on AWS server and I want the user to see and open a PDF on a specific page that is stored into my media folder after analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which library etc.

Not really a django question as @ps_ said.

**From Adobe.com**
To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add #page=[page number] to the end of the link's URL.

For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named myfile.pdf:

```html
<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">
```

Comment: Actually the Django code is running on AWS server and I want the user to see and open a PDF on a specific page that is stored into my media folder after analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my question, it took a while and after every attempt to use different libraries and PDF.js failed.
The solution is quite simple. so what I did is:

**Step 1:** Add MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL to `settings.py`.

```
# path to the MEDIA directory
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/absolute/path/to/your/media/folder' 

# URL to use to open MEDIA 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Step 2:** Update the `urls.py` with the following code:

```
from . import settings
import django

urlpatterns = [
...
...
url(r'^(.*?)media/(?P<path>.*)$', django.views.static.serve,
             {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

**Step 3:** Now I created an `onclick` in the HTML tag as:

*My pdf files were in documents folder inside the media directory*

```
onclick="window.open('media/documents/{{Your/Pdf/File/Path.pdf}}#page={{Page_number_to_open}}')"
```